# Resampling Pandas but with given dates

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample my pandas dataframe with datetime as index. When I use resample method it returns resampled date with index of the last date which doesn't always exist in the original data. For example, my original data has data from 2000-01-03 ~ 2005-12-29. But when I resample this data yearly I get data for 2005-12-31. This is a problem for me when I use concat for resampled data.

```py
Y = price.resample("Y").first()
M = price.resample("M").first()
W = price.resample("W").first()

total = pd.concat([price,W,M,Y], axis=1, sort=False)


#example

price = pd.DataFrame([1315.23, 1324.97, 1376.54, 1351.46, 1343.55, 1369.89, 1380.2 ,
       1371.18, 1359.99, 1340.93, 1312.15, 1322.74, 1305.6 , 1264.74,
       1274.86, 1305.97, 1305.97, 1315.19, 1328.92, 1334.22, 1320.28],
                     index = ['2000-12-01', '2000-12-04', '2000-12-05', '2000-12-06',
               '2000-12-07', '2000-12-08', '2000-12-11', '2000-12-12',
               '2000-12-13', '2000-12-14', '2000-12-15', '2000-12-18',
               '2000-12-19', '2000-12-20', '2000-12-21', '2000-12-22',
               '2000-12-25', '2000-12-26', '2000-12-27', '2000-12-28',
               '2000-12-29'])
price.index = pd.to_datetime(price.index)

price.resample("W").first()
#see how 12-03, 12-10, 12-17, 12-24, 12-31 are not dates that are in the original index
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: @MarkWang I have provided an example. Thank you.

Comment: dates showing up on resample (weekly,quarterly, annually) are controlled by `Anchored offsets`. By default, reasmple('W') anchors on Sunday, resample('W-MON') would make it aligned to Monday. Please refer to the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just dropping undesired rows afterwards?
The following code will work because all rows created by resample (that are not on the original index) will be set to values of `NaN`.

```
price.resample('W').dropna()
```

Comment: I don't want to drop any rows. I want to resample them with indices from the original data.

Comment: I am not sure you understand how resample works.
Resampling is used to convert a time series from one frequency to another, for example converting a daily time series to a monthly one by taking the average of each month.

Comment: I am aware it just "resamples", not take average of each month. Do I have it wrong?

Comment: It does not do this by default but it is common when you need to downsample, you run it like `.resample(...).mean()`, you are using `.first()` so this will take the first value of each month, week, year etc

Comment: Your data has missing dates, so `resample()` function will always try to fill them in order to create a time series with no missing indexes and then do the upsampling or downsampling.